# Disable the select option when the item.value is 4 coming from database but not to disable when selected item.value is 4 from the UI

Tags: angularjs

The below code shows the dropdown with the statuses `new=1, old=2, declined=3 and expired=4`. While getting the `status` from the table the all the status are displayed in the dropdown.

Requirement is to `disable` the `dropdown` for all the `expired` products from the database but it should not disable the `expired` while selecting from the UI to change the status to `expired` from `other statuses`.

Code is as below.

```
<select class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-small" 
          ng-options="item.Key as item.Value for item in ctrl.currentItem.ProductStatuses" 
          ng-model="product.Status" ng-disabled="">
    New
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to is configure the micro syntax of `ng-options` to include the `disabled` property, like so.

```
<select class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-small" ng-options="item.Key as item.Value 
                 disable when item.disabled for item in ctrl.currentItem.ProductStatuses" 
                ng-model="product.Status">
    New
</select>
```

As seen in the below example. Initially when the controller is initialized there is no `disabled` property in the array, but when the user clicks on the button, it simulates a server call, where the array contains an object with the property `disabled` set to `true`, thus the input has been disabled.

Please check the below example and let me know if this solves your issue.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
 this.currentItem = {
   ProductStatuses: [
    {Key: 1, Value: 1},
    {Key: 2, Value: 2},
    {Key: 3, Value: 3},
    {Key: 4, Value: 4}
    ]
  }
  this.serverCall = function() {
   console.log("serverCall");
   this.currentItem = {
      ProductStatuses: [
        {Key: 1, Value: 1},
        {Key: 2, Value: 2},
        {Key: 3, Value: 3},
        {Key: 4, Value: 4, disabled: true}
      ]
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController as ctrl' ng-app="myApp">
  <select class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-small" ng-options="item.Key as item.Value disable when item.disabled for item in ctrl.currentItem.ProductStatuses" ng-model="product.Status">
    New
  </select>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.serverCall()">server call</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. The code will disable the `dropdown` but not the `option` of the dropdown.
Add `ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabledProduct"` in the `select` as below.

```
<select class="uk-width-1-1 uk-form-small" 
     ng-options="item.Key as item.Value for item in ctrl.currentItem.ProductStatuses" 
     ng-model="product.Status" ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabledProduct">
   New
</select>
```

In `ng-controller` put the below code while getting the `products` from the database.
Assuming `ctrl.currentItem.Products` contains the list of products.

```
ctrl.isDisabledProduct = false;

for (var product of ctrl.currentItem.Products) {
   ctrl.isDisabledProduct = product.Status == 4;
 }
```